# Moving resource or Vnet-to-vnet peering

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have two subscription within same Azure AD Tenant and in both Subscription, VMs are running. Below are the high level details :

- Both Subscription is having one resource group each
- Both Resource group are in same region
- Vnet IP is not over lapping

So my question is whether to move all the VM's and other services in same subscription or I can go ahead with Vnet-to-vnet peering? which option is better and why?

As I need to create site-to-site connectivity as well, so if we proceed with peering option then how would be the connectivity? means how 2nd Vnet will be getting request from on-prem? or just I need to enable Gateway Transit while creating peering and everything is done or is there any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So my question is whether to move all the VM's and other services in same subscription or I can go ahead with Vnet-to-vnet peering? which option is better and why?" - there is no real answer to this question, both ways works.

You can peer across subscriptions (as long as the vnets are in the same region). You can route one VNet through the other VNet's Gateway. Most of your questions are covered by [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview).

I would probably move resources to a single subscription, as it is easier to manage them in the long term, but peering would also work.

Comment: I just found this article as well.
http://www.deployazure.com/network/virtual-network/vnet-peering-and-gateway-transit-with-s2s-vpn/
so, I can go ahead with Peering option as both subscription is serving different purpose and you also saying there is no difference as such.

Comment: thats the other article, either way, feel free to close the question or accept this as an answer @Abhishekkumar